# Surround tag with another tag in Beautifulsoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

How to surround all img tags with another tag in BeautifulSoup. This:

```
<p>
text
<img src="img1.jpg" />
..text..
<img src="img2.jpg" />
..text..
<img src="img3.jpg" />
</p>
```

should become this:

```
<p>
text
<figure><img src="img1.jpg" /></figure>
..text..
<figure><img src="img2.jpg" /></figure>
..text..
<figure><img src="img3.jpg" /></figure>
</p>
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `wrap()` function on BeautifulSoup:

```
data = '''<p>
text
<img src="img1.jpg" />
..text..
<img src="img2.jpg" />
..text..
<img src="img3.jpg" />
</p>'''

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(data, 'lxml')

for img in soup.select('img'):
    img.wrap(soup.new_tag('figure'))

print(soup.p.prettify())
```

Prints:

```
<p>
 text
 <figure>
  <img src="img1.jpg"/>
 </figure>
 ..text..
 <figure>
  <img src="img2.jpg"/>
 </figure>
 ..text..
 <figure>
  <img src="img3.jpg"/>
 </figure>
</p>
```